# Python - list of existing dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am completely new to Python, and this is just not working. 
I have these dictionaries:

```
lloyd = {
      "name": "Lloyd",
      "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
      "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
      "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
      "name": "Alice",
      "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
      "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
      "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
      "name": "Tyler",
      "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
      "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
      "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}
```

My list:

```
students_list = [lloyd, tyler, alice]
```

and I need to make a list of these so I can work out the average of all of the students' grades. 
The error I'm getting is

```
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
   def get_class_average(student_list):
       student_one = get_average(student_list["lloyd"])
       student_two = get_average(student_list["alice"])
       student_three = get_average(student_list["tyler"])

       return (student_one + student_two + student_three) /3
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include the *code*. Just an exception message is pretty useless to us.

Comment: Yep.. that would help. Sorry! I've edited it now.

Comment: Nope, still no actual code that would throw such an exception.

Comment: The code you wrote seems correct: at which point is throwing the exception?

Comment: I added the method where I'm using the list. It's throwing the error in get_class_average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that you're iterating through your list incorrectly. Try iterating like this:

```
for student in students_list:
    # perform calculation
```

Using it in your code

```
def get_class_average(student_list):
    total = 0
    for student in students_list:
        total += get_average(student)
    return total / len(student_list)
```

If you're interested in using some more complex python, try using the `map` and `sum` methods:

```
def get_class_average(student_list):
    return sum(map(get_average, student_list)) / len(student_list)
```

Comment: Don't use the name `sum` unless you're referring to the built-in function.

Comment: Good point. I've renamed the variable.

Comment: You've already got my `+1` for posting almost the exact same answer that I had (now deleted to avoid duplication), but I think a generator expression would be better than `map` in your final version. Safe to port to Python 3, too, unlike `map`.
`return sum(get_average(student) for student in student_list) / len(student_list)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a flat list:

```
>>> ns = [n for N in lloyd.values() if isinstance(N, list) for n in N]
>>> ns
[88.0, 40.0, 94.0, 90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0, 75.0, 90.0]
>>> sum(ns) / len(ns)
82.33333333333333
```